# How can I rotate a button 90° with hover in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a folding menu for my simple website and I need to rotate a button 90° when the mouse is over it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
button:hover{
  transition: 0.70s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Is the property that you're looking for.

This is not my codepen but it does show the steps needed
[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/ImageHoverEffects/pen/DyqKar)

Without seeing how you're implementing it this is the barebones, but it's worth mentioning that I recommend rotating a div surrounding the button in order to give the mouse a more lenient area for the hover to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
    button {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
           }
```